# Cobol display variable just after MOVE

Tags: cobol

Can someone explain to me what this code is doing:

```
ZAZAZA     MOVE  UT-S40-ZONES  (UT-INDS40-R)  TO   W-FH00-S40-ZONES.    PGM
ZAZAZA     MOVE  UT-S40-PERIOD (UT-INDS40-R)  TO   W-FH00-S40-PERIOD.   PGM
----->     DISPLAY "S40-ZONES-PGM::" UT-S40-ZONES  (UT-INDS40-R)           
----->     DISPLAY "W-FH00-S40-ZONES::" W-FH00-S40-ZONES                   
----->     DISPLAY "UT-S40-PERIOD::"  UT-S40-PERIOD (UT-INDS40-R)          
----->     DISPLAY "W-FH00-S40-PERIOD::" W-FH00-S40-PERIOD                 
ZAZAZA*                                                                 PGM

The display are :
S40-ZONES-PGM::******************************************
W-FH00-S40-ZONES:: empty !!!!!
UT-S40-PERIOD::"  ***************************************
W-FH00-S40-PERIOD::***************************************
```

I cannot find W-FH00-S40-ZONES:: anywhere

I have noticed that S40-ZONES-PGM and W-FH00-S40-ZONES have the same definition PICTURE X and the same size.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: all this code is doing is moving values to different variables without seeing the working storage section and the logic around this, it is hard to say what is actually going on, or even answer this question properly.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I have found the response .
In fact before those lines there is a condition IF not fulfilled.

```
zzzzzz     IF    UT-S40-REGMAL  (UT-INDS40-R) = "200"                   zzz    
zzzzzz*                                                                 zzz    
zzzzzz*                                                                 zzz    
zzzzzz     MOVE  UT-S40-ZONES  (UT-INDS40-R)  TO   W-FH00-S40-ZONES.    zzz
```

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. Since the question is very specific to your program ("the MOVE was conditional, so doesn't always happen") it's probably best to delete the question later in the day, or perhaps early tomorrow, once the people who have shown an interest in it have seen what the resolution is.

Comment: I ditto Bill: in this case it seems to be appropriate to delete the question. You find the option directly under your question.

Comment: It also illustrates why it is better to use `end-if`'s rather than ending `if`'s with a full stop